# MySQL - structuring query to discard common results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

That title is really not useful, but its a complex question (in my head, maybe) ... anywho...

Say I have a MySQL table of Countries (A-Z all countries in the world) with id & name

Then I have a table where I am tracking which countries a user has been to: Like so:

```
    Country Table
    id    name
    1     india
    2     luxembourg
    3     usa

    Visited Table
    id    user_id    country_id    
    1     1          1
    2     1          3
```

Now here's what I want to do, when I present the form to add to the list of visited countries I want country.id 1 & 3 to be excluded from the query result.

I know I can filter this using PHP ... which is something I have done in the past ... but surely there must be a way to structure a query in such a way that 1 & 3 are excluded from the returned results, like:

```
    SELECT * 
      FROM `countries` 
     WHERE `id`!= "SELECT `country_id` 
                     FROM `visited` 
                     WHERE `user_id`='1'"
```

I suspect it has something to do with JOIN statements but I can't quite figure it out.

Bonus gratitude if someone can point me in the right direction with Laravel.

Thanks you all :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your query like this.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `countries` c LEFT JOIN `visited` v on c.id = v.country_id
 WHERE v.`country_id` is null
   AND v.`user_id` = 1
```

This is a operation of a LEFT JOIN. What is means is that I'm selecting all registries from the table `countries` that may or may not is on the table `visited` based on the ID of the country.

So it will bring you this group

```
from country      from visited
     1                 1
     2              no registry
     3                 3
```

So on the where condition (`v.country_id is null`) I'm saying: I only want the ones that on this left join operation is only on the country table but it is not on visited table so it brings me the id `2`. Plus the condition that says that those registries on visited must be from the `user_id=1`

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot. Could you explain to me how it is working though? I don't like writing code I can't understand.

Comment: @sarovarc Added an explanation. :)

Comment: @sarovarc Take a look here it is a good visual explanation of the join operations: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ OR here another one: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: Hey, sorry for more trouble but .. I am using soft deletes in my visited table. How would I incorporate that into my Query?

My deleted_at column stays null until I make a soft delete. In which case it is filled with a timestamp. How can I include results that are not null?

Comment: Nevermind I managed to figure it out :)

I had to add: or "v.deleted_at is not null" at the end of my query. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
select c.*
from countries c left join
     visited v
     on c.id = v.country_id and v.user_id = 1
where v.country_id is null;
```

You can also express this as a `not in` or `not exists`, but the `left join` method typically has pretty good performance.

The left outer join keeps all records in the first table regardless of whether or not the `on` clause evaluates to true.  If there are no matches in the second table, then the columns are populated with `NULL` values.  The `where` clause simply chooses these records -- the ones that do not match.

Here is another way of expressing this that you might find easier to follow:

```
select c.*
from countries c
where not exists (select 1 from visited where c.id = v.country_id and v.user_id = 1)
```

Comment: Ok. That is exactly what I want :)

Comment: But .. but .. I really hate writing code I don't understand, could you tell me what its doing and how... please. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM COUNTRIES LEFT JOIN 
VISITED ON 
countries.id = visited.country_id and visited.country_id NOT IN ( SELECT country_id FROM visited )
```

if i understand right maybe you need something like this ?